# Docker fails when run getting-started image

Tags: macos, docker, docker-desktop

I installed the **Docker Desktop Preview** for **M1 chipset's Mac**. The installation was good and I didn't see any kind of error reported. However when I tried to run docker following the tutorial, I get the following error.

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

This is the command that show the error:

```sh
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

I don't know what I am missing, is there any way to fix this error? What is it due of?

EDIT: I fixed the issue running clean/purge the data. Now it seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here, seems to be known issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5253